# StackOverflowError when creating an object of another class

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am working on a game for the past month or so and no matter what I do, I almost always get a `StackOverflowError`. This is what it says in the trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at retroscroller.Player.<init>
at retroscroller.Hole.<init>
```

The error occurs at these lines :
(Player Class)

`Hole hl = new Hole();`

(In the hole class):

`Player ch =  new Player();`

Do I get the error because both classes are extending each other and both are superclasses ?

Comment: You have an infinite loop there, and the worst is that it involves memory usage in it.

Comment: can you please add the exception you get when you run this code?

Comment: _Do I get the error because both classes are extending each other_ - How did you manage to compile classes which extend each other?

Comment: This is basically due to infinite recursion, however, we could help you out more specifically if you post the code that you are using.

Comment: Please post more code - especially where the exception is happening.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh, ok. I knew that it involved memory usage because I got a stackoverflowerror.

Comment: Yes, the infinite loop is about constructor circular dependency. You should avoid such cases, you can solve it by passing `this` to the constructor of one of those classes instead of creating a new instance inside it.

Comment: @evanwong In the question I say where the exception is happening. The error occurs at these lines :

Comment: your "These lines: (Player Class)" doesn't help us at all. If you actually posted your code (both classes) we could actually tell you how to re-code it.

Comment: If you have a superclass `Super` and a subclass `Sub`, then you normally don't need for `Sub`'s constructor to say `new Super()`, or vice versa.  Creating a new object will create a `Sub` which already **is-a** `Super`, so no other constructor call is necessary.  Unless you really, really, really want a second object created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In most of the cases this indicates infinite recursion. Check if you are doing something of the form `A calling B calling A calling B calling A ...` where A and B are some methods/constructors. If so, restructure your code to eliminate this.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I get the error because both classes are extending each other and both are superclasses ?

No, that would be impossible at the language level. It wouldn't compile.

However, if creating a Player requires creating a Hole, which requires creating a Player... then you've got a problem. Debug into the constructor and you should see what's going on. (It's important to get familiar with a debugger... even though I prefer unit testing over debugging most of the time, sometimes you can save a lot of time by debugging...)

Consider making one of the constructors pass `this` to the other, or preferrably remove the cyclic dependency in the first place. (Do the two objects *really* need to know about each other?)

Answer (score 0):

You class will not compile. If you are using eclipse, it will complain saying

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Cycle detected: a cycle exists in the type hierarchy between <class1> 
 and <class2>
- The hierarchy of the type <class1> is inconsistent
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna(lastest version) and I NEVER got that error.

Comment: @Thor the error is not due to IDE usage, is about code design. Read JonSkeet's answer which explains the reason and how to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the object in the same class itself. e.g

```
class A{
A a =new A();
}
class Main extends {

}
```

Above code will give you always Stack overflow Exception as you can't instantiate globally